# Mounting NFS Persistent Volumes with authentication

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to mount a Persistent Volume on a self hosted Kubernetes cluster using NFS (SMB to be precise). I created a share with a user and password on another machine (my samba host), I have tested that the share is accessible from the network. So the problem is that when accessing it I would need to provide the credentials. The following is how I mount the volume:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: nfs
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  secret:
    secretName: nfs-secret
  nfs:
    path: /kubernetes
    server: 192.168.1.11
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-claim 
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

And I have tried setting up a secret, but the problem is that secrets are for passing credentials inside a pod. Have been banging my head for weeks, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you seen the solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765696/how-to-pass-user-credentials-to-user-restricted-mounted-volume-inside-kubernet

Comment: Yes, I have seen the solution but it does not work for me. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score -2):

"NFS (SMB to be precise)"

Which is it?  They are not the same thing. Your code example is showing nfs, but you said SMB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment