# How to mount NFS share with credentials with AKS POD container

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a on-prem network file share `//server_name/share` which I can map as network drive by providing credentials.

This path I am currently link with Azure VM's path `/mnt/share` and in this VM I am running docker container applications and further it will be mounted to container.

```
 - /mnt/share:/app/mnt
```

And finally my container application reading whatever available at `//server_name/share`.

Now I moved to `Azure Kubernetes Service` and here I am **NOT** able map path with my on-prem share `//server_name/share`.

What are the workaround for this issue? `Azure File Sync` I saw but this solution I don't want.

How to mount the share to the POD container?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your own NFS on the Kubernetes cluster if you are fine with that approach.

Or else you can mount the NFS file system to Kubernetes POD also.

for example :

```
volumeMounts:
         - name: nfs-volume
           mountPath: /var/your-destination
```

defining volume

```
volumes:
         - name: nfs-volum
nfs: 
           server: nfs-server.yourdomain.com
           path:/path/to/shared-folder
```

If you are looking for YAML for reference please check official examples : https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs

if you are looking forward to setup the NFS on K8s cluster you can use the : https://www.gluster.org/

Or https://min.io/

If you are looking forward to create the PV using the NFS

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: NFS server
    path: /home/shared
    readOnly: false
  storageClassName: nfs
  mountOptions: 
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
```

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_nfs.html

Comment: Thanks Harsh. I want to mount the NFS file system to Kubernetes POD. In your example where I need to put credential? This NFS can't be accessed without user/pass

Comment: https://github.com/fstab/cifs you can also use the K8s secret to store the creds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765696/how-to-pass-user-credentials-to-user-restricted-mounted-volume-inside-kubernet

Comment: Thanks. saw these link. Pretty old 3rd party and also using 3rd party

Comment: Sorry for that i will find my YAML and update the answer.

Comment: no problem Harsh. Will wait for your updated answer. Thanks and Appreciate